# Excel formula to find specific data based on max row result

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Good day beautiful people of Scotl... Stackoverflow.

I have faced issue in Excel which I have no idea how to solve. I tried many formulas but I believe that the problem is in my mind, since I have troubles to imagine the logical way it should follow.

I have attached a screenshot to clarify my problem:
[Excel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4nBe.png)

**Description of a screenshot**

Column B - data name,

Rows C3:H3 - product name,

Table C4:H15 - some data (description, dates, etc.).

Column I is my extra and it is not mandatory to be there.

**Desired result**

I want to get data from table above to the table below but if there is one or more "DataX", I want Excel to pick the "DataX" where the biggest amount of rows are filled up (I have marked them blue for each DataX).

For example, for:

Data 1 - row 4,

Data 2 - row 7,

Data 3 - (obviously) row 9,

Data 4 - rows 11,

Data 5 - row 13.

If one or more records will match (all rows are empty / filled up), I don't care which row will be presented as a result.

**What I have tried**

I have added calculation (column I) which shows how many rows were updated and I was trying to find combination of v,hlookup + max but it wasn't working correctly.

I also created VBA code for it, which was working... almost good but then I received information that macros are no-go zone for this project.

**Logic**

I strongly believe that the logic should be as following:

1. Find matching DataX,
2. Find max value in row I (or include it in formula),
3. Find corresponding rows / columns for this record.

   | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | 2 |  | CAT 1 | CAT 2 | CAT 3 | CAT 4 | CAT 5 | CAT 6 | Count not blank |
   | 3 |  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |  |
   | 4 | Data 1 | AAA | BBB | CCC |  | EEE | FFF | =$H$3-COUNTBLANK(C4:H4) |
   | 5 | Data 1 |  | BBB | CCC | DDD |  |  | =$H$3-COUNTBLANK(C5:H5) |
   | 6 | Data 1 | AAA | BBB |  |  | EEE | FFF | =$H$3-COUNTBLANK(C6:H6) |
   | 7 | Data 2 | AAA | BBB | CCC | DDD | EEE | FFF | =$H$3-COUNTBLANK(C7:H7) |
   | 8 | Data 2 | AAA | BBB | CCC | DDD |  | FFF | =$H$3-COUNTBLANK(C8:H8) |
   | 9 | Data 3 | AAA | BBB | CCC |  | EEE | FFF | =$H$3-COUNTBLANK(C9:H9) |
   | 10 | Data 4 |  |  | CCC | DDD | EEE | FFF | =$H$3-COUNTBLANK(C10:H10) |
   | 11 | Data 4 | AAA | BBB | CCC | DDD |  | FFF | =$H$3-COUNTBLANK(C11:H11) |
   | 12 | Data 4 | AAA | BBB | CCC |  | EEE | FFF | =$H$3-COUNTBLANK(C12:H12) |
   | 13 | Data 5 | AAA | BBB | CCC | DDD | EEE | FFF | =$H$3-COUNTBLANK(C13:H13) |
   | 14 | Data 5 |  | BBB | CCC | DDD | EEE | FFF | =$H$3-COUNTBLANK(C14:H14) |
   | 15 | Data 5 | AAA | BBB |  | DDD | EEE | FFF | =$H$3-COUNTBLANK(C15:H15) |

Comment: Do you have Microsoft Excel 365?

Comment: Post data as text table. What is your excel version?

Comment: Added data as text table, should help. Excel version is microsoft 365 for enterprise without insiders program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello dear son of Scotl.. overflow!
Please add to column J (range J4:J15) this additional formula

```
=CONCATENATE(B4,I4)
```

and then paste this to C19:

```
    =INDEX(C$4:C$15,MATCH(CONCATENATE($B19,MAX(IF($B$4:$B$15=$B19,$I$4:$I$15,0))), $J$4:$J$15,0))
```

paste it as an array formula, i.e. press Ctrl+Shift+Enter simultaneously. Then populate it to the rest of the desired range.

The numbers in my example table do not mean anything, it's the number in **I** that matters.
Regards!!

[image: exampleTable]